# View Records in ascending order in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a database table named LAND_MANAGEMENT. I am using a button to view the records in a datablock. I want to view the records in ascending orders but I couldn't manage to do so using the following code . Records are shown but not in any particular order.

Using the following execute_query under When-Button-Pressed trigger.

```
GO_ITEM('LAND_MANAGEMENT.SL_NO');
EXECUTE_QUERY;
FIRST_RECORD;
```

Comment: The code you've attached is not Oracle code, Please specify the programming language you are using and what have you tried so far (your query, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Forms uses the Block as its main architectural unit. So you `GO_ITEM()` is navigating to the `LAND_MANAGEMENT` block. Then the `EXECUTE_QUERY()` call issues the SELECT statement associated with that block and retrieves the data. If none is specified it defaults to `select * from` the table the block is built on,  LAND_MANAGEMENT in this case.

You are not happy with the ordering of the result set. This suggests that the query doesn't have an explicit ORDER BY clause. It's simple to add one: fire up the Block Properties editor in Forms Builder and edit **Database > Order By Clause** . (Precise navigation may vary depending on your version of Builder.)

Alternatively you can set the sort order with a call:

```
set_block_property('LAND_MANAGEMENT', order_by, 'SL_NO asc');
```